# Redux action calls converted to sequence diagram

Tags: redux

Is there any tool out there which can generate sequecne diagrams from redux actions calls ? Basically i have written a client side applciation using javascript, Redux and Angular and want to generate a sequence diagram

Answer (score 0):

The short answer: I didn't see anything like that until now.

But it should be relatively easy to implement, here are some of my thoughts:

With Redux you already should have most of the stuff in your hand:
The communication partners are various web components which are triggering actions and/or subscribing to the store.
A request between a communication partners is represented by a dispatched action.
Each time an action has been dispatched we persist (depending on the application perhaps as part of the state) the following information that is later needed to draw a sequence diagram:

- the communication partner that triggered the dispatch of the action (a property within the action)
- the action type
- the receivers, i.e. the communication partner(s) that is(are) interested in the changes that were triggered by the action. This could perhaps come from additional "acknowledgement" actions triggered by the receivers or from a static configuration that contains a mapping of which subscribers are interested in which parts of the state.